# Apply Styles on Bootstrap Select

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, select, drop-down-menu, html-select

How can I apply styles on Bootstrap Select options ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By targeting any of the internal classes.

[image]

For example:

```
.dropdown-menu a{ font-weight: bold; }
```

Comment: Thanks @Serg Chernata. How did you get this ?  I am getting like below images. 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9XRa.png